# show data online

Tags: gpio, web

I have a program that monitors the GPIO values. I have a webserver installed with some PHP and javascript (jquery) stuff and there I can plot *on-demand* results.

Is there a way to show a data stream in the web?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have a look at [Node.JS](http://weworkweplay.com/play/raspberry-pi-nodejs/) which a sperate http server that is dedicated for streaming data using SOCKETS on HTML5 or PUSHING data with some clever JS.

It might be a learning curve with Node.JS so what I would do is set the AJAX method you are using with a repeating timer in JS. Set it to like 10 seconds interval or faster if the data is not too much. That will imitate a simple "stream"

Or you could install or do some kind of SOCKET handler in PHP and use HTML5 SOCKETS on the browser to get real live stream.

Answer (score 0):

What's the program that reads the GPIO values written in? If it's PHP, then you can use JQuery and XMLHTTPRequest s to retrieve the data and render it however you want with JS.
If the program is written in, say python, then you'd have to get it to write the information to a file and have the PHP script read from that when requested by the JQuery.

Comment: this is exactly what I have, a C++ code reads and store into file. Then from the web browser a php calls this program and afterwards it returns stuff to the javascript and it is shown. But what I want (and asked for) is for a method to upload data in a stream way.

Comment: What do you mean by 'in a stream way'? If you have two pages, one that reads the file from your C++ program and returns it, and the second has JQuery to update the information on-screen by sending XHRs to the first page and displaying it.